# How to get personalized search results with youtube data API v3 using python

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How can I get personalized search results with youtube data API V3?

I connected my account with OAuth 2.0.

This is my code for searching stuff:

```
Request = Youtube.search().list(q=Video, part="snippet", maxResults=50, type="video").execute()
```

But it's not personalized

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Define personalized

Comment: based on things I watched in the past

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube api is a storage location for YouTube videos.  Think of it as Google drive for videos.  It is NOT a location for storage of what users did on YouTube that kind of tracking information is not going to be available to developers

Google isn't going to release a users browsing history that's gold to them that's what they use to keep you on their site.

Comment: But I connected to my account via OAuth 2.0, so it should have full control over my account

Comment: Yeah but i think the point of this API is to control the videos that you have uploaded, not to be able to use it as a YouTube search engine based upon your previous viewing history.

Comment: TBH its a nice idea if it was so pop it up as a feature request it would be nice to see if they would add something like that https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B